# Measure How long cloud-search API take to upload and process new document index and searchable on cloud in milliseconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

It is possible to measure How long cloud-search API take to upload and process new document and bulk document to index and searchable on cloud in milliseconds.

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Would the timings gained from this exercise be useful?  Proably not.  Voting to close as "too broad"

Comment: If possible then how ?

Comment: The only way to know that a document you uploaded has been indexed (ie is searchable) is to search for it. You could upload a doc and then, in a separate thread, poll for it via a search request until you get back a result, and then record the time.